# How to display secured SonarQube dashboard on an external TV?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

We have a TV which is used to follow development process (burn down charts, build server status etc). Some time ago we implemented a SonarQube server and decided to display some statistics on the screen. I prepared a board, but unfortunately I have a problem how to show it. The SonarQube instance is secured so only authorized users can access dashboards. I have a technical user, but I don't know how to pass credentials. I can only specify URL which will be displayed, so it is not possible to run any scripts or login the user manually.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create your own HTML/JavaScript HTML page, which uses XmlHttpRequests to access SonarQube's api (you can use a "token" for that). This is btw. what we do in our office.

Or you try to create your own HTML page with a full screen iframe, that "remote controls" SonarQube in that frame. Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure that this actually works.